# Is there a way to override/rename/remap function in php?

Tags: php

I know it's possible in other language like C++ or Obj-c even (at runtime AND compile time) but is there a way to override/rename/remap function in php? So what I mean is, let's say we want to replace the implementation of mysql_query. Is that possible?

```
SOME_REMAP_FUNCTION(mysql_query, new_mysql_query);

//and then you define your new function
function new_mysql_query(blah...) {
  //do something custom here
  //then call the original mysql_query
  mysql_query(blah...)
}
```

**This way the rest of the code can transparently call the mysql_query function and not know that we inserted some custom code in the middle.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if you make use of namespaces you can write a new function with the same name and 'trick' the system in that manner. Here's a short blog I read about it on...

http://till.klampaeckel.de/blog/archives/105-Monkey-patching-in-PHP.html

Comment: This looks promising, but requires 5.3

Answer (score 2):

As ianhales says you can do this using the APD extension or alternatively with the [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php)
Both extensions have lots of other useful in them but both can break your system in strange and exotic ways if you apply them in internet facing webservers.

A better solution is to re-write the code when you deploy it (this can be done automatically e.g. using sed) maybe making use of auto_prepend.

C.

Answer (score 0):

Not in PHP as downloaded from php.net. There's an extension that allows this though.

And if these are mysql functions you're after, better look into extending mysqli class.

Comment: It's the PECL RunKit extension that allows this

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php
This might be of some use. The top comment sounds exactly like the example you posted. It does use a PECL extension though.

Answer (score 0):

A better idea would be to use an abstraction layer from the start, such as [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  PDO ships with PHP 5.1 and newer, and is available as a PECL extension for PHP 5.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

If you have functions inside class. We can override it from other class inheriting it.

Example

```
class parent {
    function show() {
        echo "I am showing";
    }
}

class mychild extends parent {
    function show() {
        echo "I am child";
    }
}

$p = new parent;
$c = new mychild;

$p->show(); //call the show from parent
$c->show(); //call the show from mychild
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just wrap your functions within a namespace?

```
namespace MySQL
{
    function connect()
    {
         //Blah
    }
}
```

and then use like so:

```
<?php

mysql_connect(); //Native Version
MySQL\connect(); //Your Version
```

Comment: The manual says the use statement does not import functions, I wasn't able to get this example to work. If they were both in the same file perhaps it would

Comment: Updated to call directly in line, and not to use import as the situation you have discovered above.